# json unmarshalling without struct

Tags: json, go

I've following json

```
[{"href":"/publication/192a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa/article/b;version=1493756861347"},{"href":"/publication/192a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa/article/a;version=1493756856398"}]
```

Based on the given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066946/partly-json-unmarshal-into-a-map-in-go) I've tried following

```
var objmap map[string]*json.RawMessage
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &objmap)
```

I'm getting empty array with following error. any suggestions?

> json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]*json.RawMessage

Answer (score 20):

You can unmarshall to a `[]map[string]interface{}` as follows:

```
data := []byte(`[{"href":"/publication/192a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa/article/b;version=1493756861347"},{"href":"/publication/192a7f47-84c1-445e-a615-ff82d92e2eaa/article/a;version=1493756856398"}]`)
var objmap []map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &objmap); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(objmap[0]["href"]) // to parse out your value
```

To see more on how unmarshalling works see here: https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshal

Comment: Will it work for nested objects?

Answer (score 3):

This is not direct answer but I think very useful

**Json Unmarshal & Indent without struct**

```
func JsonIndent (jsontext []byte) ([]byte,error) {
    var err error
    var jsonIndent []byte
    var objmap map[string]*json.RawMessage
    err = json.Unmarshal(jsontext, &objmap)
    if err != nil {
        return jsonIndent,err
    }
    jsonIndent, err = json.MarshalIndent(objmap,"", "  ")
    return jsonIndent,err
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` is an **array** of objects, in Go the `encoding/json` package marshals/unmarshals `maps` to/from a json **object** and not an array, so you might want to allocate a `slice of maps` instead.

```
var objs []map[string]*json.RawMessage
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &objs); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/3lieuNkoUU

If you don't want to use a slice you can always wrap your json array in an object.

```
var dataobj = `{"arr":` + data + `}`
var objmap map[string]*json.RawMessage
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataobj), &objmap); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XM8MmV0gbc

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I still need more help, if you can please also println the objects after unmarshalling.

Comment: You mean printing the `json.RawMessage` objects? If so, `json.RawMessage` is just a slice of bytes, so you can print it as such, e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/jeCU6PIWYv. But I wonder, do you really want to use [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage)? It's purpose is to allow you to delay the decoding (or precomupte the encoding) of json... if you don't need those two features you are much better off using a concrete type instead.

Comment: If you don't need that precompute/delay stuff @user2727195, you should use something like this instead: https://play.golang.org/p/VKf7HgAAID