# REST API Update by partial json

Tags: json, rest, go

We are using Golang to implement a REST API which including CRUD, in Update service, client could send partial JSON including changed fields, and we need to handle for updating entity with these changes.

Logically, we need to get entity by Id from DB to struct, and then unmarshal payload json to another struct and update entity.

However if payload json is not fully, for example I have struct

```
type Customer struct {
    Id      int64 `json:"id"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Age     int `json:"age"`
}
```

And JSON request looks like

```
{
  "Name": "Updated name"
}
```

Then the customer should be updated with new name.

That's simple example, actually it could be a nested struct and nested json, how could we handle that case with golang, or event other language like Java, .NET

Comment: How are you currently unmarshaling your json into a Go struct?

Comment: You can use json.RawMessage  refer to this answer  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066946/partly-json-unmarshal-into-a-map-in-go

Comment: If you unmarshal JSON over top of an already-populated struct, only the fields in the JSON will be modified in the struct, making this trivially easy - load the record from DB, unmarshal the JSON over it, then write it back to DB. Can you show what you've tried and what issues you're having with it?

Comment: Note that by [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) you either need to use `PATCH` to perform a partial update or update a resource via `PUT` that partially overlap the actual resource. To the actual resource this has the effect of a partial update then, though the semantics of `PUT` remain: replace the current payload of the targeted resource with the payload provided in the request. Anything other is a violation of the HTTP protocol. Also, patching should send instructions to the server on how to modify the resource to end up in a desired state.

Comment: The closest thing you might want to do is `PATCH`ing the resource with media-type `application/merge-patch+json` as spedified in [RFC 7396](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7396) and only for such media-types. I'd still recommend to use `application/json-patch+json` as specified in [RFC 6902](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) though

Answer (score 2):

If the Update request uses the same `Customer` struct then the struct fields could be pointers to differentiate between zero value and value not being set in the JSON.
Now all you need to do is merge existing struct into updated `Consumer` struct.
For this you can use https://github.com/imdario/mergo library in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/imdario/mergo"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type Address struct {
    City string `json:"city"`
}

type Customer struct {
    Id      int64 `json:"id"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Age     int `json:"age"`
    Address *Address `json:"address"`
}


func main() {
    old1 := &Customer{Id:1, Name:"alpha", Age:5, Address:&Address{City:"Delhi"}}

    b := []byte(`{"name": "beta"}`) //no address, age specified picks from old
    up1 := new(Customer)
    json.Unmarshal(b, up1)
    if err := mergo.Merge(up1, old1); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err in 1st merge: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    m1, _ := json.Marshal(up1)
    fmt.Printf("merged to: %v\n", string(m1))

    old2 := &Customer{Id:1, Name:"alpha", Age:5, Address:&Address{City:"Delhi"}}
    b2 := []byte(`{ "address": {"city": "mumbai"}}`) //address specified
    up2 := new(Customer)
    json.Unmarshal(b2, up2)
    if err := mergo.Merge(up2, old2); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err in 1st merge: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    m2, _ := json.Marshal(up2)
    fmt.Printf("merged to: %v\n", string(m2))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Saurav Prakash, but if I want to update value of Age to 0, it's impossible with this framework

Answer (score 0):

from your comments it seems you are hitting the zero-value issue a lot of users with `go` encounter i.e. how does one tell if the input data passed a legitimate value - or was that value zeroed by default omission.

The only way to solve this is to use pointers. So in your example, changing your data struct to this:

```
type Customer struct {
    Id   *int64  `json:"id"`
    Name *string `json:"name"`
    Age  *int    `json:"age"`
}
```

Then after unmarshaling, any uninitialized fields will have `nil` values e.g.

```
var c Customer

err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &c)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

if c.Id != nil {
    log.Println("TODO: added SQL update parms for c.Id:", *c.Id)
}
if c.Name != nil {
    log.Println("TODO: added SQL update params for c.Name:", *c.Name)
}
if c.Age != nil {
    log.Println("TODO: added SQL update parms for c.Age:", *c.Age)
}
```

Note: care must be taken to ensure one does not accidentally reference any nil pointers which would trigger an instant `panic`.

Working [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/aP1CHzCBJjo).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to partial unmarshal JSON like [Protocol Buffers FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf?hl=en#fieldmask)

- First deserialize restful api request JSON to `map[string]interface{}`
- Then convert `map[string]interface{}` to a FieldMask through [fieldmask](https://github.com/RussellLuo/fieldmask)
- Finally parse `map[string]interface{}` into a struct through [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure)

Here is one code sample

```golang
 type Customer struct {
     Name    string `json:"name"`
     Age     int    `json:"age"`
     Address string `json:"address"`
 }

 func (p *Customer) Update(other Customer, fm fieldmask.FieldMask) {
     if len(fm) == 0 {
         *p = other
         return
     }

     if fm.Has("name") {
         p.Name = other.Name
     }
     if fm.Has("age") {
         p.Age = other.Age
     }
     if fm.Has("address") {
         p.Address = other.Address
     }
 }

 type UpdateCustomerRequest struct {
     Customer
     FieldMask fieldmask.FieldMask `json:"-"`
 }

 func (req *UpdateCustomerRequest) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
     if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &req.FieldMask); err != nil {
         return err
     }
     return mapstructure.Decode(req.FieldMask, &req.Customer)
 }

 func PartialUpdate() {
     customer := Customer{
         Name:    "foo",
         Age:     20,
         Address: "address 1",
     }
     fmt.Printf("init: %#v\n", customer)

     blob := []byte(`{"age": 10, "address": "address 2"}`)
     req := UpdateCustomerRequest{}
     if err := json.Unmarshal(blob, &req); err != nil {
         fmt.Printf("err: %#v\n", err)
     }

     customer.Update(req.Customer, req.FieldMask)
     fmt.Printf("updated: %#v\n", customer)

 }
```